# How to exclude certain directories/files from `consult-git-grep` search?

Tags: git, grep, consult

I want to exlude certain files such as `.gitignore` in [`consult-git-grep`](https://github.com/minad/consult) search.

- `consult-git-grep` works find with following defualt setup:

`(setq consult-git-grep-args "git --no-pager grep -F -n --no-color -I -e '%s')`

I have updated `consult-git-grep-args` definition where `-- '(exclude).gitignore'` is added at the end, but it crashes. How could I make it work?

**init.el**

```
(require 'consult)
```

Followed by:

`(setq consult-git-grep-args "git --no-pager grep -F -n --no-color -I -e '%s' -- '(exclude).gitignore'")`

---

Related: [How to exclude certain directories/files from counsel-git-grep search?](https://github.com/minad/consult/issues/395#issuecomment-897901286)

> `consult-git-grep already` ignores files you put in `.gitignore`. In
> order to exclude additional files you can write on the
> `consult-git-grep prompt`:
>
> `#foo -- :!*.org` `#foo -- :!.gitignore` This will search for foo and
> ignore `*.org` files or the file .gitignore. If you want to hard code
> these settings adjust the variable `consult-git-grep-args`, which is
> similar to `counsel-git-grep-cmd-default`.